# Manually setup a NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I wanted to use Window.Forms, in particular charts within .Net 5.
Therefore, I manually downloaded "system.windows.forms.datavisualization.1.0.0-prerelease.20110.1.nupkg" from the NuGet website, which is still a prerelease.
I applied Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Package Sources to setup the new path, where I saved the nupkg file.
Unfortunately, trying to finally install the package via the Solution explorer > Managing NuGet Packages > Browse, the nupkg file will not be found.

Comment: any particular reason why you didn't just install it directly via nuget?

Comment: ```Install-Package System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization -Version 1.0.0-prerelease.20110.1``` why u do not using via pm...?

Comment: It doesn't show up using the vs 2019 NuGet package manager. It only shows a different package Maikebing.System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.